# Get list of all NUnit tests and custom properties

Tags: .net, selenium, unit-testing, nunit, testrail

My organization is in the process of realigning our QA processes and have purchased the test management tool TestRail. We are importing all of our existing UI automation tests into TestRail so that we can create test plans and store historical test run data on a per test basis. Within TestRail, you are able to make test runs, which contain subsets of your full test library, that aid you in testing features without having to run all your tests.

Our test library is developed with Selenium in Visual Studio, and each test is set up as a NUnit Unit test. Each test has a NUnit property "tr_id" which maps to it's TestRail test case's identifier.

I am developing an integration through the TestRail API that pushes test results on a per test basis to TestRail, but the way it currently works, all tests will run, even tests that aren't in a given TestRail test plan. Through the TestRail API I am able to pull a list of all tests in a given test plan and store all of the test ids into a list (which is then comparable to the tr_id on the Selenium NUnit tests).

The question I am most looking forward to answering is if there is any way to get all NUnit tests and their properties that I can then parse through to create a subset of tests to run, while ignoring all other tests that are not part of the TestRail test plan.

I'm running into an issue with how we can make the UI Framework run *only* tests that are in the test runs as identified within the test plans as identified in TestRail.

What I am trying to do is the following (pseudocode):

```
listA = TestRail.GetTestsIdsInPlan(planA);
listB = NUnit.GetAllTestsIds(); //from custom property tr_id
listC = empty list;

foreach(testId id in listA)
{
    if (listB.Contains(id))
    {
        listC.Add(id);
    }
}
```

By doing this, I would then run all tests that are within listC since the ids matched to tests that are in the test run.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know anything about TestRail but this seems overly complicated. NUnit alone will allow you to tag scripts by feature area or how ever you want and then run scripts by tag as a command line parameter. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create specific test execution lists, that will only execute a test case if certain conditions are met -- i.e., part of your test plan or where tr_id is not blank.

This problem is best handled in the automation code itself. I recommend going through the code and separating out test cases based on how you want to run them -- create a folder called `SmokeTestCases`, and only put automated test cases from your smoke suite in there. You can make another folder called `NeedsTestRailId`, and put all of the untagged automation test cases in there. You can do the same thing for Regression test cases, etc.

Once your test cases have been split up in the code itself, this will make it much easier to create specific execution lists.

Using NUnit.ConsoleRunner, you can execute specific subsets of test cases. First, you want to create execution lists -- these are simple .txt files containing the namespace of the tests you wish to run. Given your automation project is called `TestAutomationSuite` and it contains folders `SmokeTest`, `RegressionTest`, and `NotTagged`:

SmokeTestList.txt

```
TestAutomationSuite.SmokeTest
```

RegressionTestList.txt

```
TestAutomationSuite.RegressionTest
```

You can also use this namespace syntax to pick specific tests, rather than an entire folder:

```
TestAutomationSuite.RegressionTest.MyTestClass_1.MyTest_1
TestAutomationSuite.RegressionTest.MyTestClass_1.MyTest_2
TestAutomationSuite.RegressionTest.MyTestClass_2
```

So the bulk of this problem can be solved by reorganizing your automation code solution, and by creating smart execution lists that can be passed into NUnit.ConsoleRunner.

In order to actually execute these tests, you need to use NUnit.ConsoleRunner through the command line. This will also produce a helpful XML output file that you can parse & publish the results to TestRail.

Documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

In a nutshell, you can run NUnit.ConsoleRunner like this:

1. Open command prompt
2. `cd ProjectDirectory\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner\tools`
3. `nunit3-console C:\ProjectDirectory\Project.dll C:\ProjectDirectory\RegressionTestList.txt`

More info can be found in the NUnit documentation, but the first argument is the path to the .dll of the C# project you wish to run, and the second argument is the path to the execution list you wish to run.

If you do not like the idea of creating specific test run lists, you can try using the `--where` flag supported by NUnit.ConsoleRunner. I have not used this one personally, so I would refer to the documentation on this if I were you.

Hope this helps a bit. Feel free to ask me any additional questions.